# Progress bar's Visibility property not changing during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I want to be able to hide a progress bar once a button is pressed, but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is my progress bar in XAML :

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" IsIndeterminate="True" Height="37" Margin="0,10,0,10" Visibility="{Binding ProgressVisibility,  Mode=TwoWay}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
```

In my .xaml.cs I have this dependency property :

```
    public Visibility ProgressVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ProgressVisibilityProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ProgressVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProgressVisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ProgressVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(RecipeDownloadDialogStatusView), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));
```

And in the view model I have this property :

```
    private Visibility progressVisibility;
    public Visibility ProgressVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return this.progressVisibility;
        }

        set
        {
            this.progressVisibility = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ProgressVisibility");
        }
    }
```

When a button is pressed, I call :

```
ProgressVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

While debugging :

- The line above gets executed but nothing happens.
- The setter gets called and so is the OnPropertyChanged
- The dependency property gets registred.

I'm not really sure what did I do wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Whats the need of dependency property here? Did you set DataContext properly?

Comment: I want to add an animation later, but that's irrelevant at this point

Comment: Is the getter called as well? Maybe you have a problem with the `DataContext`

Comment: you need to process the command property in the button and change the visibility property in the view model, also you can set the name for the progressbar and change its visibility property in the code behind like ProgressBarName .Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

Comment: Since you have two properties for some reason, the question is which property do you set and which property do you bind to? You need to bind to the property that you set then the `Button` is clicked.

Comment: @FlatEric Yes the getter is called.

Comment: Show your `Button_Click` handler. Also please take a minute and read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I think one of two things is the problem here:

1. The `DataContext` of the `ProgressBar` is set to your viewmodel but your `Button` is only updating the property of your parent control / window.
2. The `DataContext` of the `ProgressBar`is set to your parent control / window but your `Button` is only updating the property of your viewmodel.

If you want `ProgressVisibility` to be publicly available, change it to

```
public Visibility ProgressVisibility
{
    get => this.viewModel.ProgressVisibility;
    set => this.viewModel.ProgressVisibility = value;
}
```

If `ProgressVisibility` does not need to be public, just drop the dependency property and work with the implementation in the viewmodel instead.

Comment: There can be also a third thing.. ;)

Comment: @Rekshino what's the third thing?

Comment: First I want to see `Button_Click` handler.